# OnChangeListener on Picker in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, picker

Am having two pickers and i got each `SelectedItem` from the **Pickers** but they are not Firing my Method whenever  i change there Values Why ?

**Below is my Code :**

*This how i declared the selected Indices of Each Picker:*

```
int selectedIndexYear = year_pk.SelectedIndex;
int selectedIndexTerm = term_pk.SelectedIndex;
```

*Here is the logic behind of firing whenever i change the picker , but it's not working :*

```
if (selectedIndexYear != -1 && selectedIndexTerm != -1)
{
    int term = Int32.Parse(term_pk.SelectedItem.ToString());
    //Below  is my method am Firing Each change of the Picker.
    OnResultsList(year_pk.SelectedItem.ToString(), term);
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what is going wrong with this snippet.  I'd set a breakpoint and step through in the debugger to work out what is going wrong.

Comment: Man tried that also but not working

Comment: In that case it sounds as though your event handler isn't being invoked.  Perhaps post a complete simple example including the Xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that scenario , i see you want to fire an Event whenever there's a change of an Item selected on a picker.

I recommend you to use `SelectedIndexChanged` Event as below :

```
year_pk.SelectedIndexChanged += delegate 
{
    int term = Int32.Parse(term_pk.SelectedItem.ToString());
    //Below  is my method am Firing Each change of the Picker.
    OnResultsList(year_pk.SelectedItem.ToString(), term);
}

term_pk.SelectedIndexChanged += delegate 
{
    int term = Int32.Parse(term_pk.SelectedItem.ToString());
    //Below  is my method am Firing Each change of the Picker.
    OnResultsList(year_pk.SelectedItem.ToString(), term);
}
```

Comment: Let me give this a shot and see